# No result when searching for specific stock

Tags: yahoo, yql, yahoo-finance

i am playing around with the yahoo yql.
If i do a search on:
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2A%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22CARL-B.CO%22%29&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&format=json

It works as expected.

If i do a search on this:

https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2A%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22MAERSK-B.CO%22%29&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&format=json

I get no result.

If i search both symbols here:
https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/CARL-B.CO

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MAERSK-B.CO

Both works just fine.
Am i doing something wrong or are there some kind of limitations on some stocks/shares?

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: I have python code yes. But first, do both links works when opened directly in your browser? I don't think any code will produce another result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is http://datatables.org/ . Currently not working.

Comment: But it does not explain why the CARL-B.CO works and MAERSK-B.CO does not...

Comment: YQL uses to store its open data table definitions on datatables.org. Maybe cached on the server.